# How is HBase packaged in HDP different from Apache HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

How is HBase packaged in Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP) different from Apache HBase. We use HDP in production but for dev purposes, test with Apache HBase.

What should we do in our code to allow for any differences?

Comment: What particular problems have you observed?

Answer (score 0):

HDP packages all open source components. There should be no difference